# First differential of Bockstein Spectral Sequence (Confused)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

[image]

In this paragraph above, it is claimed that $\partial\circ{\text{red}_p}_*=\beta$.

Q1) How do we see this?

Q2) Furthermore I am confused by the fact that a few pages earlier, the Bockstein homomorphism $\beta$ was defined as:

$$\beta: H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z})\to H_{n-1}(X;\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z})$$
$$\bar{u}=\{c\otimes 1\}\mapsto\{v\otimes 1\}=\{\frac{1}{r}\partial c\otimes 1\}$$

I am confused that the domain and codomain of $\partial\circ{\text{red}_p}_*$ and $\beta$ don't even match, how can they be equal?

For instance the domain of $\partial\circ{\text{red}_p}_*$ is $H_*(X)$, while the domain of $\beta$ is $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z})$. Even if $r=p$, there seems to be a mismatch.

Thanks for any help.

(Btw the book is McCleary's User Guide to Spectral Sequences)

Comment: This is a typo. McCleary means to write $d^1=red\circ \partial=\beta$. Then

1) This is the definition of the Bockstein (see pg. 127).

2) Calculate the Bockstein using the defintion and this is what you get.